# ICP4D - Installed but not able to create new project

Tags: menu, installation, openshift, project

I have installed the ICP4D, IBM Cloud Pak For data, on an Openshft cluster with a master, infra and 2 worker nodes.

What I do not see is the Project menu? What could be wrong?

And how do I correct it? Screen shot attached below:

[image]

Thanks,
CS

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you have installed the base product, but not the add-ons you are interested in.  The components of CP4D are available to be installed on top of the base, and will enable the various menu options as you add them.

For example, you might want to install the Watson Studio Local, Watson Machine Learning, and Jupyter Notebook add-ons to get started with open source data science and Python.

You can browse the available add-ons by clicking the squares icon in the top right.

[image: Services Menu for Addons]

In that menu you can browse to see what you have installed, and what are available (included in CP4D), and what are Premium (additional purchased functionality).

See additional details on installing Watson Studio Local (for example), here; https://www.ibm.com/support/producthub/icpdata/docs/content/SSQNUZ_current/wsj/install/install-ws.html

Let me know if this helps.

Comment: Yes, I followed that link, but still errors are thrown up for 2.5 version of CP4D: I still get this error of product life cycle not specified.

Comment: @user1303002 sorry I just saw the comment. Have you loaded any of your desired assemblies before browsing that add-on catalog with the `cpd-linux` comamnd?  You'll want to load those assemblies and then deploy from that menu will work and expand your choices in projects.